# how to identify connection error in python?

Tags: python, exception, connection, suds

In python we get different exception for diff connection issues like ECONNREFUSED, ECONNRESET, EHOSTUNREACH etc. Is there any standard logic for identifying connection errors in python? Basically I am using suds for connecting to vmware WS SDK and I want to re-try session login on connection errors.

Comment: How are you creating the connections? Using the `socket` module? Anyway on python3.3 the I/O exception hierarchy was rewritten(see the [what's new](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-3151)). In particular you can use `ConnectionAbortedError`, `ConnectionRefusedError` and `ConnectionResetError`. In previous versions of python you should catch `IOError` and examine the error number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced exactly this problem today and I wrote a blog post about it:
https://gmpy.dev/blog/2023/recognize-connection-errors

```py
import errno, socket, ssl

# Network errors, usually related to DHCP or wpa_supplicant (Wi-Fi).
NETWORK_ERRNOS = frozenset((
    errno.ENETUNREACH,  # "Network is unreachable"
    errno.ENETDOWN,  # "Network is down"
    errno.ENETRESET,  # "Network dropped connection on reset"
    errno.ENONET,  # "Machine is not on the network"
))

def is_connection_err(exc):
    """Return True if an exception is connection-related."""
    if isinstance(exc, ConnectionError):
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ConnectionError
        # ConnectionError includes:
        # * BrokenPipeError (EPIPE, ESHUTDOWN)
        # * ConnectionAbortedError (ECONNABORTED)
        # * ConnectionRefusedError (ECONNREFUSED)
        # * ConnectionResetError (ECONNRESET)
        return True
    if isinstance(exc, socket.gaierror):
        # failed DNS resolution on connect()
        return True
    if isinstance(exc, (socket.timeout, TimeoutError)):
        # timeout on connect(), recv(), send()
        return True
    if isinstance(exc, OSError):
        # ENOTCONN == "Transport endpoint is not connected"
        return (exc.errno in NETWORK_ERRNOS) or (exc.errno == errno.ENOTCONN)
    if isinstance(exc, ssl.SSLError):
        # Let's consider any SSL error a connection error. Usually this is:
        # * ssl.SSLZeroReturnError: "TLS/SSL connection has been closed"
        # * ssl.SSLError: [SSL: BAD_LENGTH] bad length
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard logic in python is to catch exceptions using `try/except` construction: [Handling Exception in Python](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: What I asked is, Is there a standard list of exceptions which denotes a connection issue.

Comment: It depends on package structure. For example, `suds` uses following exceptions:AttributeError, BuildError, Exception, KeyError, MethodNotFound, PathResolver.BadPath, PortNotFound, ServiceNotFound, StopIteration, TypeNotFound. All expcetions related to network raised as instance of Exception class. There is not special parent of network- or connection-related common exceptions parent like NetworkError.